# Can't create any objects within OLAP database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas

**Problem**

I can't create any objects under my databases in my Analysis Server. My context menus on all the folders under this `test` database just have `Refresh` as an option.

[image]

**Details**

My Analysis Server is running locally. I am a local admin. I am running SSMS as Administrator.

I have tried running the Analysis Services as both Local System and my user.

[image]

During setup, I added my user to the list of users who can administer Analysis Services.
[image]

**More Information**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio you can access deployed Analysis databases. You cannot create OLAP objects (Data Sources, Data Source Views, Cubes, Dimensions). In order to do that, you have to download SQL Server Data Tools and create these objects using Visual Studio then deploy them to the SSAS database.

*SQL Server Data Tools download link:*

- [Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)